# Sending ETHM to my ETH wallet address in Coinbase Wallet results in the ETHM being sent back to my ETHM wallet

Tags: ether, wallet-transfer, coinbase

Using Coinbase wallet, I sent ETHM to my ETH wallet address (ETHM is ERC20). The transaction was successful and I was charged a fee. In Coinbase Wallet I now see the ETHM back in my ETHM wallet, which was sent there from my ETH wallet address. How can I transfer the ETHM to ETH? I can do it in Uniswap, but Coinbase wallet is reflecting a much higher rate for the ETHM, so I want to do the swap there.

Comment: What is an "ETHM wallet"? If you have the private key (or the mnemonic) you can do a transfer for an arbitrary ERC20 from MyEtherWallet or MyCrypto (you will need some ether to pay for the transaction fees).

Comment: @Ismael, thanks. By 'ETHM wallet' I mean the ETHM (Ethereum Meta) in my Coinbase wallet. Sorry I'm a noob, I may be using the wrong term. Could MyEtherWallet or MyCrypto allow me to convert my ETHM to ETH in my Coinbase wallet? That's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: There are Coinbase exchange and Coinbase wallet.In the exchange you can trade supported tokens. The Coinbase wallet is just a wallet and don't have the functionality to trade by itself, but you can send them to an exchange. In order to transfer any token you need some ether to pay the transaction fees. Most wallets do not have a token swap functionality by themselves but some of them rely on third parties for it. In any case unless your wallet is from exchange you will have to pay the transaction fees.